# Why do some browsers attempt to render assembly language files as HTML?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-browser

So, why do Internet Explorer 6 and the Android Stock Browser 4.1 (and possibly some other browsers I haven't tested it on) attempt to render Assembly language source files (.ASM files) as if they were HTML?

Try to open this web-app (that converts arithmetic expressions to i486-compatible assembly) and click the link to download the fully prepared Assembly language project (or just the link to download the example project):
http://flatassembler.000webhostapp.com/compiler.html

They are supposed to download those files, but instead they attempt to render them as HTML. In order to download those files, the user has to manually save them as if they were web-pages. What's going on? Is there a way to code against it?

Also, probably related to that, why is it that only Safari downloads those Assembly language files, while most of the modern browsers just render them as if they were plain-text files? Is there a way to code against that (so that they download the .ASM files automatically, not that the user has to copy-paste the text or manually save the file)?
Don't tell me to use `window.download`, it doesn't work in any browser I've tested that on.

Comment: Do you really care about IE6?

Comment: @Pointy It's not just IE6. IE6 and Android Stock do something VERY wrong, while some other browsers do something similar, but less wrong.

Comment: In any case it's absolutely not clear where the "download" link is in your linked site.

Comment: @Pointy It's the first link named "here".

Comment: Well the response for that `download.asm` link doesn't even set the `Content-Type` header, let alone `Content-Disposition`. How is the browser supposed to know that it's intended to be a download?

Comment: @Pointy So, how can I possibly set the Content-Type header? It's not like it's a PHP file.

Comment: Well *any* working server-side infrastructure should be able to set response headers. I mean, that's a pretty basic part of the job of being a "web server".

Comment: @Pointy OK, I'll try to find out how to set that. What Content-Type header and Content-Disposition would you suggest me to set for assembly language source files?

Comment: [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) is the key to telling the browser you've got an "attachment" for download.

Comment: @Pointy OK, thanks, that works in Android Stock Browser. And people who use Internet Explorer today hopefully know what they are doing :).